# Why does Intellisense show a variable as an option on the right side of its declaration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

In this example below, Visual Studio gives me Intellisense for a variable I haven't finished declaring / instantiating. Is this variable really in scope and could be used on the right side of it's own declaration? If not, why does Intellisense show it as an option? Is this just a quirk about how Intellisense works?

```
var myVariable1 = 1;
// throws compiler error, but VS offers it as an option of something to type
// when I start typing "myv"...
var myVariable2 = myVariable2;
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I can't reproduce that, my intellisense doesn't show `myVariable2`

Comment: Visual studio without Resharper shows it, With Resharper enabled I can only see `myVariable1`

Comment: Yeah, I don't have Resharper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the variable really is in scope. That's just how declarations work.

Ordinarily, it doesn't make sense to refer to the variable being declared in its own initialiser, and for local variables, the compiler will not allow you to observe the value before it's initialised. But a use of that variable that doesn't rely on it being initialised can show you that it really is in scope. For non-local variables, they have a default value, so the initialiser is well-defined if it refers to the variable.

```
static class Program {
  static int f(out int i) {
    return i = 0;
  }
  static void Main() {
    int i = f(out i); // okay
  }
  static int j = j; // okay
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also going to ask what scenarios in which doing so would be valid, but I wasn't sure if there would be any. Cool! And annoying!